# Spring cloud function written in Kotlin for AWS Lambda fails

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, aws-lambda, spring-cloud

I am trying to deploy a Spring Cloud Function written in Kotlin as an AWS lambda, but getting this error when testing it out

```
{
  "errorMessage": "No bean named 'function' available",
  "errorType": "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:686)",
    "org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1205)",
    "org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)",
    "org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)",
    "org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1091)",
    "org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringFunctionInitializer.initialize(SpringFunctionInitializer.java:100)",
    "org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootRequestHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootRequestHandler.java:44)"
  ]
}
```

I am able to run it fine on my local setup uisng spring-boot:run command.
I am using spring boot 2 with spring 5.
Here is what my code looks like.

**Application.kts**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@FunctionScan
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

**Function.kt**

```
package `in`.nafa.job.inventoryfulfillment

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import java.util.function.Function
@Component("function")
class Function : Function<Incoming, Outgoinig> {
    override fun apply(t: Incoming): Outgoinig {

        return Outgoinig()
    }
}
```

Incoming and Outgoing are empty classes and do not have any properties.

**Handler.kt**

```
package `in`.nafa.job.inventoryfulfillment

import org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootRequestHandler

class Handler : SpringBootRequestHandler<Incoming, Outgoinig>()
```

**pom.xml**
Most part of this pom is copied from [spring cloud function samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/master/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-aws/pom.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>in.nafa.job</groupId>
    <artifactId>inventory-fulfillment</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>inventory-fulfillment</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.2.20</kotlin.version>
        <aws-lambda-events.version>2.0.2</aws-lambda-events.version>
        <reactor.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</reactor.version>
        <wrapper.version>1.0.9.RELEASE</wrapper.version>
        <spring-cloud-function.version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud-function.version>
        <spring-cloud-stream-servlet.version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud-stream-servlet.version>
        <start-class>in.nafa.job.inventoryfulfillment.InventoryFulfillmentApplicationKt</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-web</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>${aws-lambda-events.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-function.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-stream-servlet.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                        <version>${wrapper.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>aws</shadedClassifierName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working by changing my start class in pom.xml from

```
<start-class>in.nafa.job.inventoryfulfillment.InventoryFulfillmentApplicationKt</start-class>
```

to

```
<start-class>in.nafa.job.inventoryfulfillment.InventoryFulfillmentApplication</start-class>
```

Hope this helps someone..

Comment: The other option is to specify `MAIN_CLASS` environment variable in AWS Lambda configuration and set it to `in.nafa.job.inventoryfulfillment.InventoryFulfillmentApplication`